# Docker: Can I access to system files?

Tags: file, docker, docker-image

I am confused to respect the access to system files of the OS where the docker engine is running on. Is this possible?
 I think that in certain cases I'll need to use certain files to run tests or for reading files for other processes. What should I do in this cases? create an image with the files that I'll need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have your container access files on your host where `docker` is running you would typically use [volume mounts](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/dockervolumes/#mount-a-host-directory-as-a-data-volume).  A common idiom is something like this:

```
docker run -v .:/src myimage /src/run-my-tests
```

That is, mount my current working directory as `/src` in the container, then run some sort of shell script that performs tests.

You can use volume mounts to access any files or directories on your host.  For example:

```
docker run -v /:/host ...
```

Will give you access to the entire host root filesystem.  Running:

```
docker run -v /etc/motd:/etc/motd ...
```

Would replace `/etc/motd` in the container with the one on your host.  Read the docs for more information.